# Selenium- getting correct menu count

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to get a count of links  from top menu.

http://test1.absofttrainings.com/

Here is the xpath I am using:

```
List<WebElement> home_menu=br.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://test1.absofttrainings.com/')]/following-sibling::*//a"));
System.out.println(home_menu.size());
```

Problem: It prints out 17 while I am expecting 6. What would be the correct way of writing xpath so that it prints out 6?

More info:

```
List<WebElement> home_menu=br.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://test1.absofttrainings.com/')]/following-sibling::*//a"));
        System.out.println(home_menu.size());
        for(WebElement e: home_menu){
            System.out.println(e.getText());
        }
```

print out:
17
Home
Shop
Cart
My Account
Test Pages

How to Use

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by *links from top menu*?

Comment: Upon visiting the site, on the top left you will see
Home Shop Cart MyAccount TestPages HowToUse Search (icon)
Some of those items have drop downs but the number of top menu is 7.

I hope I was able to clarify the question. Basically my end goal is to use an assert where I will expect 7 menu items in homepage.

Thank You

Comment: Search button is not a link. Do you still want your XPath to return this element?

Comment: No, I do not want that in my Xpath , so the count should be 6,using the code above I get the following output

17
Home
Shop
Cart
My Account
Test Pages


How to Use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below XPath to get required (6) elements only

```
//ul[@id='top-menu']/li/a
```

Answer (score 0):

By executing $x("//a[contains(@href,'http://test1.absofttrainings.com/')]/following-sibling::*//a") in the browser console, there are 17  objects.

There is a hidden menu for mobile devices in the website, and your xpath cannot get rid of it. By deleting , now there are 8 objects left.
These 8 links are actually the first 6 menu items + 2 sub-menu items under "Test Pages". In other words, the search button is not captured by your xpath as well.

For selecting the first 6 menu items, execute this xpath,
$x("//nav[@id='top-menu-nav']/ul/li/a")

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Count_menu() {   

     List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://****=')]"));

     System.out.println("Total menu are "+links.size());
     int no=1;
     for (int i = 1; i<links.size(); i=i+1)      
     {      
         if(links.get(i).getText().isEmpty()) {

         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
            no++;               
         }       
     }  
     System.out.println("Total final menu are "+no);        
    }
```